# Showing that $\sqrt[3]{9+9\sqrt[3]{9+9\sqrt[3]{9+\cdots}}} - \sqrt{8-\sqrt{8-\sqrt{8+\sqrt{8-\sqrt{8-\sqrt{8+\cdots}}}}}} = 1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, real-numbers, nested-radicals

$$\sqrt[3]{9+9\sqrt[3]{9+9\sqrt[3]{9+\cdots}}} - \sqrt{8-\sqrt{8-\sqrt{8+\sqrt{8-\sqrt{8-\sqrt{8+\cdots}}}}}} = 1$$
In the second nested radical, the repeating pattern is $(-,-,+)$. I approached this problem in a rather boring way. That is, the first expression satisfies the equation,
$$y=\sqrt[3]{9+9y} \implies y^3=9+9y$$
and the second one satisfies,
$$x=+\sqrt{8-\sqrt{8-\sqrt{8+x}}} \implies \left[(x^2-8)^2-8\right]^2=8+x$$
Now this magically factors into 
$$(x^2 - x - 8) (x^3 - 2 x^2 - 11 x + 23) (x^3 + 3 x^2 - 6 x - 17) = 0$$
It turns out that the $x$ we are looking is the solution of the third factor. And so,
$$x^3 + 3 x^2 - 6 x - 17=0 \implies (x+1)^3-9(x+1)-9=0$$ 
And magically $x+1=y$. The problem here is that this does not give me much understanding of nested radicals, it is just plain bash.

> **Q.** All in all, my question asks, if there's a way to prove the difference
>   is 1 without (or a little less) bashing and a nice general way to deal
>   with such expressions (like the examples below)?

---

Next I tried the following, Assume that we want to solve
$$t=\sqrt{7-\sqrt{7+\sqrt{7-\sqrt{7+\sqrt{7-\sqrt{7+\cdots}}}}}}$$
What we can try is the following,
$$t=\oplus\sqrt{7\ominus\sqrt{7+t}}$$
When we repeatedly square, we loose the information of the signs highlighted. That is, the equation $(t^2-7)^2=t+7$ has some nice roots corresponding to,
$$t=+\sqrt{7+\sqrt{7+t}}\qquad \text{and}\qquad t=-\sqrt{7-\sqrt{7+t}}$$
But these can be reduced by their symmetry,
$$t=+\sqrt{7+t}\qquad \text{and}\qquad t=-\sqrt{7+t}$$
Solution to both of these satisfy $t^2=t+7$ (which are the roots we don't want). And so we get the intuition why that huge equation has a quadratic factor. Now in this case, after long division we will end up with a quadratic equation whose solution (that we want) is $2$. If we use this in our original question, we get a 6th degree equation with no further intuition.

I also saw this on Wikipedia with no explanation.
[image]
There is a typing error in the above image.
[image]

Comment: i think that whatever we do , in the end we have to solve a polynomial to get the value of the nested radical.

Comment: In the nested radical with $7$s, what symmetry are you referring to? Anyways, since $t\ge 0$ you can neglect the case where $t$ is negative

Comment: How do you define the second repeated radical? Why did you say "It turns out that the x we are looking is the solution of the third factor." What prevents other factors from being also being valid solutions to the nested radical?

Comment: I'm not sure what's the question here.

Comment: @AnotherJohnDoe $t=\sqrt{7+\sqrt{7+t}}$ forms the infinite nested radical expression $\sqrt{7+\sqrt{7+\sqrt{7+\cdots}}}$ which can be easily solved as the root of $t=\sqrt{7+t}$. Same with its negative brother.

Comment: @Mark Define $x_0=0$ and then recursively define, $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{8-\sqrt{8-\sqrt{8+x_{n}}}}$, And so, $x=\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n$. Using a calc, you can see, $x\approx 2.41$. Now we had $x=\sqrt{8-\sqrt{8-\sqrt{8+x}}}$, converting this into an 8th degree equation will add 7 other roots which does not interest us. It then turns out the root of the equation near $2.41$ satisfies the third factor.

Comment: @Ennar My question asks, if there's a way to prove the difference is $1$ without (or a little less) bashing. Continuing this question, I want to know is there a nice general way to deal with such expressions? One thing good enough to conjecture is, if the length of the repeating part is $k$, the value of the expression is root of a $k$th degree equation. Like here the repitition was $(-,-,+)$ and so was a root of a cubic equation and similarly, the last expression i found on wikipedia $(++-+)$ is a root of a quartic equation.

Comment: @SubhajitHalder This is too elegant to be proven by the method I provided, and it does not seem to be a coincidence.

Comment: I suggest you write that explicitly in the body of the question. I don't know any general methods other than what you've done. I didn't try it, but for the last nested radical you wrote, it's easy to write down condition $\sqrt{5+\sqrt 5} < x < 20$, so Rouche's theorem might eliminate everything but the quartic.

Comment: Just also numerical calculation offer the difference is 1. Again also graphical image offer difference is 1. Neither exact method, though.

Comment: I got the elegant method from Will Jagy, but long way for me. hint you can get trigonometric solution, and two trigonometric values would give 1.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Trigonometric_solution_for_three_real_roots

Comment: the final claim from wikipedia is false. The left hand side satisfies an irreducible sextic, numerically 2.747664892845112497700424585. The right hand side satisfies a quartic,  2.747238274932304333057465186

Answer (score 1):

took me a while. The roots of your
$$ u^3 - 9u - 9 = 0 $$
are
$$  -2 \sqrt 3 \sin {\frac{2\pi}{9}} \; ,     $$
$$  -2 \sqrt 3 \sin {\frac{8\pi}{9}} \; = \;  -2 \sqrt 3 \sin {\frac{\pi}{9}} ,     $$
$$  -2 \sqrt 3 \sin {\frac{14\pi}{9}} \; = \; 2 \sqrt 3 \sin {\frac{4\pi}{9}} .     $$

============================

```
? poldisc( s^3 - 9 * s - 9)
%51 = 729
? polgalois( s^3 - 9 * s - 9)
%59 = [3, 1, 1, "A3"]

? polroots( s^3 - 9 * s - 9)
%52 = [-2.226681596905677465811651808 ,
       -1.184792530904095372701352048 , 
        3.411474127809772838513003856 ]~


? u = -2 * sqrt(3) * sin (2 * Pi / 9  )
%53 = -2.226681596905677465811651808
? v = -2 * sqrt(3) * sin (8 * Pi / 9  )
%54 = -1.184792530904095372701352048
? w = -2 * sqrt(3) * sin (14 * Pi / 9  )
%55 = 3.411474127809772838513003856
? 
? u^3 - 9 * u - 9
%56 = 0.E-27
? v^3 - 9 * v - 9
%57 = 0.E-27
? w^3 - 9 * w - 9
%58 = -8.07793567 E-28
?
```

===========================

[image]

Comment: Leaving aside how that answers the question, how can your initial quadratic polynomial have three different roots?

Comment: @HenningMakholm typo corrected. The sort of thing it answers is discussed here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1065862/something-strange-about-sqrt-4-sqrt-4-sqrt-4-x-x-and-its-friends

Answer (score 1):

You also asked about $$x =\sqrt{ 5+ \sqrt{ 5 + \sqrt{ 5-x}}}$$
I figured out how to express $x$ in radicals.

Take
$$ k = \frac{1 + \sqrt {13}}{2} $$
so that
$$ k^2 - k + 2 = 5 \; .  $$

Then $x$ above is the largest root of the cubic
$$ x^3 + (k-1) x^2 - (k^2 + 2)x - (k^3 - k^2 + 2 k - 1) $$  which is the same as
$$ x^3 + (k-1) x^2 - (k+5)x - ( 5 k - 1) $$

```
? k = (1 + sqrt(13))/2
%5 = 2.302775637731994646559610634
?  h = x^3 + (k-1) * x^2 - (k^2 + 2) * x - (k^3 - k^2 + 2 * k - 1 )
%6 = x^3 + 1.302775637731994646559610634*x^2 
    - 7.302775637731994646559610634*x - 10.51387818865997323279805317
? polroots(h)
%7 = [-2.549662363373543544157989866 + 0.E-28*I,
      -1.500778167203563600102045353 + 0.E-28*I,
       2.747664892845112497700424585 + 0.E-28*I]~
? w = x^3 +(k-1) * x^2 - (k+5) * x - (5 * k - 1) 
%8 = x^3 + 1.302775637731994646559610634*x^2 - 7.302775637731994646559610634*x 
       - 10.51387818865997323279805317
? polroots(w)
%9 = [-2.549662363373543544157989866 + 0.E-28*I, 
      -1.500778167203563600102045353 + 0.E-28*I, 
       2.747664892845112497700424585 + 0.E-28*I]~
?
```

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

In general, with positive integer $a \geq 2$ and real $k > 0$ such that
$$  k^2 - k + 2 = a, $$ so that
$$ k = \frac{1 + \sqrt{4a-7}}{2} \; , $$
with $$x =\sqrt{ a+ \sqrt{ a + \sqrt{ a-x}}},$$ we find $x$ is the largest root of
$$ x^3 + (k-1) x^2 - (a+k)x - ( a k - 1) \; .$$
We can use Cardano at this point. The bad news is that the cube roots will be of complex numbers, we are in [Casus Irreducibilis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis).

[image]

Comment: I just now realized that there is a typing error in the image I got from Wikipedia. They say that repeating pattern is ++-+ but actually in the image it is ++- . Maybe this is the problem... (Sorry for the trouble I caused you) the only reason I added the image was to know what will happen when repeating pattern has a length of 4 or more.

Comment: Ramanujan gave the simpler forms of such radicals [Here](https://i.imgur.com/GgIM0yq.png): Take,
$$x=\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a-x}}}$$
Then
$$x=\frac{1-\sqrt{4a-7}}{6}+\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{4a+\sqrt{4a-7}}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\arctan\left(\frac{1+2\sqrt{4a-7}}{3\sqrt{3}}\right)\right)$$

Using these you can get the closed form for $\sqrt{8-\sqrt{8-\sqrt{8+..}}}$ in the question. I have seen no paper talk about, except for [this](http://ms.uky.edu/~corso/Ramanujan_Monthly_article.pdf) stating this without any explanation at Eq. $3.3$