# Equation $x=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+x}}}$

Tags: trigonometry, radicals

> The value of $x$ satisfying the equation $x=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+x}}}$ is given by
>
> 1. $2 \cos(10°)$
> 2. $2 \cos(20°)$
> 3. $2 \cos(40°)$
> 4. $2 \cos(80°)$

Using $x=2\cos(\theta)$  we get
$2\cos(\theta)=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+2\cos\theta}}}$

$2\cos(\theta)=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-2\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}}$

$2\cos(\theta)=\sqrt{2+2\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{4}\right)}$

$4\cos^2(\theta)={2+2\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{4}\right)}$

After this step I am not able to solve it

Comment: Have you tried rewriting cos in terms on sin or the other way around?

Comment: Rather than squaring in the last step, try using the half-angle identity one more time. (Also, it may help to remember that $\sin(\theta)=\cos(90^\circ-\theta)$.

Comment: After the last step, subtract 2 from both sides and use double angle formula for cos to get: $2\cos^2(\theta) - 1= \cos (2\theta)=sin{\frac{\theta}{2}}$ and then use complementary angle formula.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1065862/something-strange-about-sqrt-4-sqrt-4-sqrt-4-x-x-and-its-friends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My illustration is outlined below

$\begin{array}{l}
4{\cos ^2}\theta  = 2\left( {1 + \sin \frac{\theta }{4}} \right)\\
4{\cos ^2}{10^o} \ne 2\left( {1 + \sin \frac{{{{10}^o}}}{4}} \right)\\
4{\cos ^2}{10^o} \ne 2\left( {1 + \sin {{2.5}^o}} \right)\\
4{\cos ^2}{10^o} \ne 2\left( {1 + \cos {{87.5}^o}} \right)\\
\\
4{\cos ^2}{20^o} \ne 2\left( {1 + \sin \frac{{{{10}^o}}}{4}} \right)\\
4{\cos ^2}{20^o} \ne 2\left( {1 + \sin {5^o}} \right)\\
4{\cos ^2}{20^o} \ne 2\left( {1 + \cos {{85}^o}} \right)\\
\\
4{\cos ^2}{40^o} = 2\left( {1 + \sin \frac{{{{40}^o}}}{4}} \right)\\
4{\cos ^2}{40^o} = 2\left( {1 + \sin {{10}^o}} \right)\\
4{\cos ^2}{40^o} = 2\left( {1 + \cos {{80}^o}} \right)\\
\\
4{\cos ^2}{80^o} \ne 2\left( {1 + \sin \frac{{{{80}^o}}}{4}} \right)\\
4{\cos ^2}{80^o} \ne 2\left( {1 + \sin {{20}^o}} \right)\\
4{\cos ^2}{80^o} \ne 2\left( {1 + \cos {{70}^o}} \right)
\end{array}$\

Hence the option is $0=40^o$